# Trying to make gallery with views in Drupal 7

Tags: media

I have made 2 content types one is called Series and the other is Pictures. I have made a field on Pictures that will reference to Series. Using views I made a tab menu page that will appear on only the Series content type. What I'm having trouble is having to show all the Pictures that is referenced to that series. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This question could use a bit of clarification.

> Using views I made a tab menu page that will appear on only the Series content type

What does the view currently display if not all the pictures associated to the series? Just every single pictures that exists in the database? Or doesn't display anything? If it displays every single picture existing, then you need to add a "Contextual filter" to the view, choose the field that you use to reference the series. And choose "Provide a default value" and choose "Content ID from URL" option.

For display I would use HTML List type of views, and use image presets (core) to display the thumbnails and use [lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) (contrib) module to display the large image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module?  It is a module written specifically for creating slideshows in Views and is well-supported (well documented; video tutorials are available) on both Drupal 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a page view of nodes with content type:picture set page url to something `node/%/pictures` and add contextual filter of reference field.
It will show all the pictures of particular series.

Answer (score 0):

Or use an existing module, [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) for example.

If you really want to create your own, using Contextual filters like Baysaa explained should work.